# Parameters of function of numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: swift, tableview, datasource

I set the `TableView` `DataSource` in the following way:

```
MyTable.dataSource = ViewController
```

With the `ViewController` that implement the protocol `UITableViewDataSource`.
I use the following code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
```

Which initializes the parameters present in this function?
Does the data source automatically put the instance `MyTable` in the parameter `tableView`?

Answer (score 1):

The tableview asks the dataSource by calling this method when it needs to display the table.

Answer (score 1):

The table view itself is calling the data source method on the delegate you assign to it. When the table view calls the method, it passes itself (`self`) as the argument to the `tableView` parameter. It also passes the section number to the `section` parameter.

Inside the implementation of the `UITableView` class is something like this:

```
let numberOfSections = dataSource.numberOfSections(in: self)
for section in 0..<numberOfSections {
    let rowCount = dataSource.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
}
```

That's not actual table view code but a rough example to give you an idea of what is going on.